# Connect mongoose database Visual Studio code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, visual-studio-code

Hei, I am creating a blog with Node and mongoDB. I am working with visual Studio code.
I installed mongoDB and create the Azure extension and it seems that everything is working good. When I run the command mongod, it says "waiting for extension" but then when I run my app nothing happens. The app opens but is not connecting to the database or giving any errors. Did I miss a step? Can someone explain me what is missing? I follow each tutorial/explanation for each step and all of them work individually(add mongoose, create the Cosmos DB extension, etc) but with the app...nothing... And if I go to the command Mongo no db is there. Also in cosmos 
Any idea would be appreciated.
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Map global promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Mongoose Connect
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-blog', {})
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you hadn't added the promise. Also, if you're able to connect to a database instance somewhere else like mLab or something. It could help identify where to look.